# Replacing multiple string Replace() with a single Regex.Replace()

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

if I'm doing something like that:

```
someString.Replace("abc","").Replace("def","").Replace(@"c:\Windows","")
```

How can I replace that with

```
Regex.Replace(someString," \\here I don't know what the pattern should be")
```

I've tried this:

```
Regex.Replace(someString, @"(?:abc|def|c:\Windows)")
```

but it didn't work

UPD...

The problem is when I pass the path like that

```
Regex.Replace(someString, @"(?:abc|def|"+aPath+")")
```

Comment: make sure all backslashes are escaped. `\ ` should be `\\ `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
`But it didnt work` doesn't say much helpfull!
```

Try this:

```
someString = Regex.Replace(someString, @"(?:abc|def|ghi|c:\\Windows)", "")
```

It did work when I tried it. I thinks the reason why your code doesn't work is because you forgot the replacement string and you have to escape the backslash in the path.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming the thing that "didn't work" is your C:\windows replacement. You need

```
someString = Regex.Replace(someString, @"(?:abc|def|C:\\windows)","");
```

The problem is you need to escape your backslash. An unescaped backslash has meaning in regex. In particular, in this case, \W actually matches any non-alphanumeric character.

**Edit** to escape an any arbitrary string, you can use `Regex.Escape(yourString);`

Comment: what if I'm passing a path like this: 
Regex.Replace(someString, @"(?:abc|def|"+aPath+","")